# How to dynamically change tabs sizes in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, cross-platform

I'm a student working on my first Qt program and I need some help. I'm developing a musical instruments simulator. I have a mainwindow and 2 classes: DrumsWindow and KeysWindow simulating drums and keys and having different sizes (drums are 798x532, keys are 953x306). I have created a tabWidget in the main window and inserted my DrumsWindow and KeysWindow into it:

```
ui->tabWidget->insertTab(0, &dw, "Drums");
ui->tabWidget->insertTab(1, &kw, "Synth");

if (ui->tabWidget->currentIndex() == 0){
    this->resize(798, 532);
    ui->tabWidget->resize(798, 532);
}

if (ui->tabWidget->currentIndex() == 1){
    this->resize(953, 306);
    ui->tabWidget->resize(953, 306);
}
```

This code is from the MainWindow constructor. It works, there are two tabs in the main window showing drums and keys. However, those "if" statements make only the first opened tab of the proper size. When I click on the Synth tab, window size remains the same (while I need it to be changed). So, this is what I made to solve the problem. First, I created new slots in the MainWindow class:

```
void MainWindow::drumsTabClicked()
{
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
    this->resize(798, 532);
    ui->tabWidget->resize(798, 532);
}
void MainWindow::keysTabClicked()
{
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
    this->resize(953, 306);
    ui->tabWidget->resize(953, 306);
}
```

And then, I connected them to signals:

```
connect(ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabBarClicked(0)), this, SLOT(drumsTabClicked()));
connect(ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabBarClicked(1)), this, SLOT(keysTabClicked()));
```

But still, it doesn't work. Could you, please, explain how to resize the main window when the user clicks on a tab?

Comment: connect(ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabBarClicked(0)), this, SLOT(drumsTabClicked()));

This is no valid connect statement. Please read about [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: Off topic but... explicitly sizing widgets is almost always the wrong thing to do.  Unless you've got good reason to do otherwise you should just let the layouts do their job.

Comment: You use Qt4 style to connect signals. That's old and not recommend anymore. Since Qt5, there is a new style which is evaluated at compile time (in opposition to runtime evaluation until Qt4). Additionally, you don't need explicitly remarked slots anymore but can connect every invocable with matching signature (lambdas included). FYI: [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: I agree with @G.M. concerning the window resizing. I can imagine that you have a certain idea in mind but trying to do it in Qt is fighting against windmills. Instead you should try to layout in grids (or boxes) where the grid cell sizes are (automatically) determined at runtime by Qt itself. Thereby, you only adjust which cells are allowed to grow (to fill available extra space) and which not. Finally, you (probably) will realize that this makes layout and maintenance easier. FYI: [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Comment: I understand that "explicitly sizing widgets is almost always the wrong thing to do" but my program is a simulator of a musical instrument that has a photo of an instrument on each tab. The sizes of the photos are fixed, so, in order to save them from cropping, I need to change the geometry of the window. And I cannot apply any layout because I need each button to have a fixed position on the photo, matching the part of the instrument it should simulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, you helped me a lot. Here's what I did.

**mainwindow.h:** added a slot

```
private slots:
    void onTabBarClicked(int);
```

**mainwindow.cpp:** added the realization of the slot

```
void MainWindow::onTabBarClicked(int index){
    if (index == 0){
        this->resize(798, 532);
        ui->tabWidget->resize(798, 532);
    }
    if (index == 1){
        this->resize(953, 306);
        ui->tabWidget->resize(953, 306);
    }
}
```

And connected the slot and the signal using Qt5 syntax:

```
connect(ui->tabWidget, &QTabWidget::tabBarClicked, this, &MainWindow::onTabBarClicked);
```

So, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You should connect it like this:

```
connect(ui->tabWidget, SIGNAL(tabBarClicked(int)), this, SLOT(onTabBarClicked(int)));
```

Then do your stuff in this slot and seperate them with if:

```
void MainWindow::tabBarClicked(int index)
{
    if(!index)
    {
        this->resize(798, 532);
        ui->tabWidget->resize(798, 532);
    }
    else
    {
        this->resize(953, 306);
        ui->tabWidget->resize(953, 306);
    }
}
```

Also you can create this connection automatically with right click on UI form tab bar and select go to slot **tabBarClicked**.